# accessing state inside calculatestate from componentdidmount

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am new to flux and react and I would like to know how can I access state inside calculatestate() from 
componentdidmount()?

how can I access events state inside componentdidmount()? I would like loop through events and then run a query per event, which in turn updates another store.

```
static getStores() {
  return [SomeStore];
}
static calculateState(prevState, props) {
  const somestore = SomeStore.getState();

  return {
    events: SomeStore.getState(),
  };
}

componentdidmount(){

  //this.state.events;
  //need to do some query based on the events
  //this query will update another store.
}
```

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: no update so far. I tried to create a simple React app using Flux and Flux container, it gave me an error when using Flux container. Something like this: you need to declare .... with new keyword..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the lifecycle methods to understand the `componentDidMount` method which are outlined [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)

To initialise the localstate, you should use the constructor method (static can also be used as an alternative, but jsfiddle throws an error.

To show the initial state, you can log within `componentDidMount` with `this.state`.

```js
const someStore = ["event"];

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { events: someStore };
  }

  // if you want to change state based on props
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // change state if you want here
    if (this.state.events.length !== nextState.events.length) {
      console.log(this.state, nextState)
      return true // update
    }

    return false
  }

  // get initial state
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.events);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>example</span>
        <button onClick = {() => {
          this.setState(state => {
            return {
              events: [...state.events, "new event"]
            }
          })
        }}>Add Event</button>
        
        <div>
          events: { JSON.stringify(this.state.events) }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: as you have described it I can do it, but how do you get the state from `calculateState()`?  It works fine inside `render` method, but not in componentdidmount().
your example does not implement flux/redux.

Comment: flux is a design pattern whereby the state is update based on how you set your initial state and whatever updates to the state are immuttable

Comment: redux isn't included in your example, and if you want a redux solution - you should include a codesandbox example -

Comment: your redux state you map it to component props. your react component state has no relation with redux state, they are different. for mapping you use redux's connect function as the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) says. like `connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)` where mapStateToProps is a function that receives redux state as param

Comment: I'd say - like, if we get more info on how the redux state is connected, we can elaborate but should allow OP to explain more - I dont think i can expand the answer without more context, happy to remove answer later

Comment: agree, need more context to ellaborate better answer. Though given op replies it looked to me that he is confused about redux state and react state, which is somewhat common when you start with redux.

Comment: yeah agreed - happy to edit later, but can allow the OP to expand - 

Also happy to upvote your answer if you post something in the coming days if i dont edit in time

Comment: I also find the use of static methods out of the react lifecycles somewhat uncommon - so that's partly confusing from my end. I haven't seen this as a common coding pattern - is that something you've noticed?